# Is it ok to call PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences() with a destroyed activity as the context?

Tags: android

In my android app, I do an asynchronous task, and when this task is complete, I need to save a value retrieved through the asynchronous task in shared preferences. I do it like below.

```
performAsyncTask((value) => {
    // this is the async task complete callback
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putLong("some_pref_key", value).apply();
});
```

There is a chance that the activity has been destroyed at the time of the async task completion, so a destroyed activity would be passed passed as the context to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

I tested this and it worked without an issue, but I am not sure whether this can cause problems in some situations. Does anyone know whether this can lead to unexpected issues?

Answer (score 1):

No, sharing the Activity context to an AsyncTask is not a good idea and leaks may occur. Suppose, your Activity has been destroyed due to a configuration change and `onDestroy()` has been called, so it should be garbage collected. But you keep a reference of it inside the **inner annonymous class** (callback) which prevents the Activity instance to be garbage collected until the task finishes. Hence, leak may occurs when your long running task continues for a long period. You should use Application context instead. [Ref1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes#3-scope-of-variables), [Ref2](https://www.programmersought.com/article/73921511531/)

Comment: Is there a possibility to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` and `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` return two different shared preference objects? I use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` in various other places to access the value saved in this async task, so it is required to have the same shared preferences returned in both, otherwise application would work incorrectly.

Comment: So far as I know, they all are same.

Answer (score 0):

It might in theory, since as you said if the activity in question could be destroyed then it can in a way. Most likely the context will be null. But there is a simple solution to that, just use the `getApplicationContext()` instead for saving it then.

It will ensure it stays even if the activity in question is destroyed.